# No emulator installed (but not work) - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using Android studio (2.3.3).

When I want to create a Virtual Device, it shows "No emulator installed" (per the picture, below).

My problem is, when I click `Install Emulator` , it does not work; nothing is downloaded. How can I solve this?

The app does run in Mobile / tab.

[image]

Comment: Have you downloaded the relevant SDK Platform from the SDK Manager?

Comment: yes . downloaded from SDK Manager .

am i uninstall android studio and again install it ??
or have it any other solution ??

Comment: @Sheiblu still stuck?

Comment: @wick , No this problem is solve . in SDK tool , uninstall  "Android Emulator " and again install "Android Emulator " .

Answer (score 0):

for windows got to -> turn windows features on and of if Hyper-v is selected , then deselect it and restart your pc.

1. then open android studio->sdk manager -> sdk Tools and download Anroid Emulator
   it should work.

if not then

2. go to your sdk folder where you have installed it. then extras->intel->Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager->intelhaxm-android
   install it if not and pray for it to the almighty :)